# In Minecraft, how to make every world have it's own modpacks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I have like 5-6 worlds that I use and every of them needs a different mod setup. I am slowly run out of folders `mods1`, `mods2`, `mods_`, .. for each of the world, where `mods` is the current time launching minecraft.

How to make my time easier? Is it possible with one click load the mods I need for every single map? The worlds are also of different versions (1.14.x and 1.12.2).

Comment: How can you run out of folders? If you have a FAT32 file system, you can have up to 65535 folders in the same folder, on other files systems more. Just creating a "void" type superflat world in 65535 previously empty Minecraft data folders would take up 163GB of disk space, not even including any mods or actually playing. So no, you're probably not running out of folders. ;)

Comment: I mean / I don|t remember which folder belongs to which world. I remember there was something about twitch or steam or a similar app, that could load the mods based on the world.

Comment: It can't do it based on the world. Every version of minecraft, when you load it, loads with a certain set of mods. It stays with that set of mods until it is closed. Any worlds associated with that set of mods will only work with that set of mods.

Comment: But.. what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got the solution:

- Install Twitch
- Select the modpack you want or

  - create a profile
  - and chose the mods.
- Enjoy the game.

That's a solution that'll fit me.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to load a different version of minecraft every time you want to change world.

Every version of minecraft, when you load it, loads with a certain set of mods. It stays with that set of mods until it is closed. Any worlds associated with that set of mods will only work with that set of mods, meaning to go to different worlds, you'll have to close your minecraft and open another instance with the mods that world requires.